# Gross domestic spending on R&D data

Tags: panel-data, dataset, survey, macroeconomics

I'm looking for data about R&D  but I just found OECD data until 1981, so do you guys know where can I find data for R&D spending before 1981. Sorry if here it's not the place to ask for this

Comment: There are some pre-1981 OECD numbers at https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=GERD_FUNDS_PRE1981 and https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=PERS_OCCUP_PRE1981 but also a lot of gaps, and no assurance that they are consistent with the post-1981 numbers